# Remove "Revision Information" Section?

Tags: nodes

For my use case, I don't need this Revision information section to appear on my page. (I am using revision, so it has to be enabled on the content type).

What options are there to 1) disable this seciton , or to 2) hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more user-friendly experience to content editors.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, I would love it if you marked it so.

Comment: @SandsHakimi : looking at your profile it shows that you never visited the "tour" (within the help pages, upper right). Which is also why you're probably not aware of what's written in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ... Moreover, lookiing at all your (10) questions I noticed that you have never marked any of them as "accepted" (and I'm not sure if you ever upvoted any of them). Know that if you never accept or upvote any answers, the nr or answers to future questions may slow down ... Just trying to help you to get going on Drupal.SE, ok?

Comment: Interesting module for "enhancing the content editor experience", didn't know about that! +1 ...